# Tailwindcss, cannot get image that I want in the background to go to bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to create a background that has a video (z-index -2) and a image that goes over it (z-index -1). I have achieved this however I cannot get the image to go to the bottom where the footer is. I am not too sure which css I need to get this too happen.

I have tried for a couple of hours trying to get it to the bottom.

[image: Image of house needs to go to the bottom]

I am using create-react-app and tailwindcss

Background.js

```
import React from "react";

import BackgroundVideo from "./BackgroundVideo";

import testVideo from "../../media/videos/test_video.mp4";
import homeSkyline from "../../media/images/homeSkyline.png";
import BackgroundImage from "./BackgroundImage";

function Background() {
  return (
    <div className="fixed h-screen w-screen overflow-hidden">
      <BackgroundVideo video={testVideo} />
      <BackgroundImage image={homeSkyline} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Background;
```

BackgroundImage.js

```
import React from "react";

// provides image and styling for Background
function BackgroundImage(props) {
  const { image } = props;

  return (
    <div className="relative z-negative1 h-screen w-screen">
      <img src={image} alt="" className=" min-w-10 inset-x-0 bottom-0" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default BackgroundImage;
```

BackgroundVideo.js

```
import React from "react";

// provides video for Background and styling
function BackgroundVideo(props) {
  const { video } = props;

  return (
    <video
      className="absolute z-negative1 min-h-none min-w-none max-w-3xl md:max-w-none"
      autoPlay
      loop
      muted
    >
      <source src={video} type="video/mp4" />
      Your browser does not support the video tag
    </video>
  );
}

export default BackgroundVideo;
```

App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Activities from "./pages/Activities";
import About from "./pages/About";
import Contact from "./pages/Contact";
import Book from "./pages/Book";

import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import Background from "./components/background/Background";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="relative flex flex-col h-screen w-screen justify-between z-1">
      <Background />
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/activities" exact component={Activities} />
          <Route path="/about" exact component={About} />
          <Route path="/book" exact component={Book} />
          <Route path="/contact" exact component={Contact} />
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: background image container you can simply use flex and align items to end of container which is height of screen as i see, that should work

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks for that!

Comment: That's Great :)

Comment: @Manjunath you should post it as answer to get upvotes

Comment: @vanowm Yeah but it was simple and did not need much of explaining so commenting was better :)

Comment: @Manjunath But the whole point of answering is for the next person looking for a solution could find it 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Manjunath for the answer,

background image container you can simply use flex and align items to end of container which is height of screen as i see, that should work – Manjunath May 6 at 5:54